# How To Open System Directories In Finder Without Opening A New Finder Tab

Tags: macos, finder

In the finder I made hidden directories visible. The odd thing is that any system directory (IE one whose name starts with a ".") I can't open them by double-clicking on them. Instead I have to right click and and select to open in a new tab. Is there a way to change this behavior?

I'm using Mavericks, not sure if this issue is specific to Mavericks or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter those directories from keyboard with <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>↓ Down arrow</kbd>.
 Or <kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and type the name of the directory You want to enter. You can complete directory name with <kbd>⇥ TAB</kbd> button (for example type `Down` in `$USER` dir, press <kbd>⇥ TAB</kbd> and it will become `Downloads`).

Comment: I like that cmd + down arrow, but I'd really like to just be able to double click it.